# unexpected memory error when trying to train CvANN_MLP ann from xml file

Tags: c++, xml, opencv, machine-learning, ocr

I am trying to classify numbers from input image to my code
I created a OCR_3.xlm file and I think there is no problem with that,
but when I try to train CvANN_MLP and I got an error that says:

***OpenCV Error : Assertion failed (y==0 || (data && dims >= 1 && (unsigned)y < (unsigned)size.p[0])) in cv::Mat::ptr , file D:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\Mat.hpp, line 429***

Here is my code:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
```

{

```
FileStorage fs;
fs.open("OCR_3.xml", FileStorage::READ);
Mat trainData;
Mat classes;
fs["TrainingData"] >> trainData;
fs["classes"] >> classes;

int const nlayers = 10;
CvANN_MLP ann;
int const numCharacters = 9;
int buffer[] = { trainData.cols, nlayers, numCharacters };
Mat const layers(1, 3, CV_32SC1, buffer);
ann.create(layers, CvANN_MLP::SIGMOID_SYM, 1, 1);

Mat trainClasses(trainData.rows, numCharacters, CV_32FC1);
for (int i = 0; i != trainClasses.rows; ++i){
    int const labels = *classes.ptr<int>(i);
    auto train_ptr = trainClasses.ptr<float>(i);
    for (int k = 0; k != trainClasses.cols; ++k){
        *train_ptr = k != labels ? 0 : 1;
        ++train_ptr;
    }
}

Mat const weights = cv::Mat::ones(1, trainData.rows, CV_32FC1);
ann.train(trainData, trainClasses, weights);



return 0;
```

}

I have been working on this about 3 months, I really don't know what the problem is, can you please help me going through this, maybe there is problem in the .xml file

You can download my ocr_3.xml file from this URL:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/g32cm20f13hffpu/OCR_3.xml?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

read this tutorial for how to prepare a data file 
https://github.com/bytefish/opencv/blob/master/machinelearning/doc/machinelearning.pdf

Note : that newest version of OpenCv  - 3.0  - machinelearning module rewritten
So after making correct data file code must be  adapted to new version

http://docs.opencv.org/master/db/dfa/tutorial_transition_guide.html